# Typo3 10.4 - How to add FAL image to my extension

Tags: typo3

I'm a new Typo3 user and I'm trying to add images to my extension with using FAL.

I found some old docs and posts on stackoverflow to help me for adding FAL to add images, I'm using 10.4 version.

I configured my TCA, my locallang, and the model but the field doesn't appear in backend, the sources used were quite old I don't know if I missed something to make it works

I added it in my Configuration/TCA like that :

```
        'image' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextension_domain_model_atelier.image',
            'config' =>
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                    'image',
                    [
                        'appearance' => [
                            'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                        ],
                        'foreign_types' => [
                            '0' => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'foreign_match_fields' => [
                            'fieldname' => 'image',
                            'tablenames' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_atelier',
                            'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                        ],
                        'maxitems' => 3
                    ],
                    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
                ),

        ],
```

Language/locallang.xlf :

```
<trans-unit id="tx_myextension_domain_model_atelier.image">
   <source>image</source>
</trans-unit>
```

Model :

```
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     */
    protected $image;


    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $image
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $image
     * @return void
     */
    public function setImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }
```

can someone tell me if i missed something, or if i made a mistake? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i can see that you are missing is whenever you use ObjectStorage, you have to initialise it first. That means, in your model, you have to do something like this:

```
/**
* Initializes all ObjectStorage properties when model is reconstructed from DB (where __construct is not called)
* Do not modify this method!
* It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
* You may modify the constructor of this class instead
*/
public function initializeObject()
{
   $this->image = $this->image ?? new ObjectStorage();
}
```

The second thing you have to do in order to display it in your Backend, you have to add it on the `types`. The types are responsible for the backend view, and you can configure the order which your columns, tabs and palettes are displayed.

```
return [
    'ctrl' => [...],
    'types' => [
        '0' => [
            'showitem' => 'hidden, image, sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource'
        ],
    ],
    'columns' => [...]
];
```

Comment: thanks you, my issue is solved, and you learned me something about ObjectStorage